# Php(woocommerce): Pass $variables as array values

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

For the moment I am using array values like this:

```
$product_ids = array(7657,7995,8000,7999,7998,7997,7996,8001,8002,8485,8486);
```

then I managed to get above values throught a function like this:

```
$ProductPhoneModelID = get_all_products_ids(catid->38);
```

when echo the function is printing values like it should:

```
7657,7995,8000,7999,7998,7997,7996,8001,8002,8485,8486
```

But when i try to use the variable to get values the array seems empty:

```
$product_ids = array($ProductPhoneModelID);
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: What does `var_dump($ProductPhoneModelID);` print?

Comment: string(54) "7657,7995,7996,7997,8485,8486,7999,7998,8000,8001,8002"

Comment: Try - `$product_ids = explode(',', $ProductPhoneModelID);`

Comment: its returning Array besides i am already using implode in the function

Comment: Oh I see it instead of $product_ids = array($ProductPhoneModelID); use $product_ids = explode(',', $ProductPhoneModelID);

Comment: @SougataBose This question appears unresolved since there is no posted answer.  Please write your comment as an answer so that: mysticalghoul can award it the green tick of approval (instead of upvoting your comment), future SO readers won't have to read all of the comments to discover the answer, and other coders won't try to solve this already-solved issue.